# Pagination returns a result after last page has been reached

Tags: entries, pagination

I understand I can use a conditional to output a 'next page' link only when next pages exist, but I am finding a problem with direct URLs.

Let's say you have 20 entries and 10 per page.

The URL **/news** (or **/news/p1**) and **/news/p2** should work, but I would expect **/news/p3** to show no results or a message.

What I'm finding however is that **/news/p3** and beyond returns the last entry in the collection.

Here's the template code:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section(listingSection).order('postDate desc').limit(2) as entriesOnPage %}

    <div class="ral-loading ral-hero-block ral-headline">Loading the latest content...</div>

    <div class="isotope js-isotope" >

        {% for entry in entriesOnPage %}

            {% if entry.section.handle != 'tweet' %}

                {% switch entry.tileSize %}

                    {% case "Single" %}

                        {% include '_partials/_isotope_block_single.html' %}

                    {% case "Double Horizontal" %}

                        {% include '_partials/_isotope_block_horizontal.html' %}

                    {% case "Double Vertical" %}

                        {% include '_partials/_isotope_block_vertical.html' %}

                    {% case "Quadruple" %}

                        {% include '_partials/_isotope_block_big.html' %}

                    {% case "Quote" %}

                        {% include '_partials/_isotope_block_quote.html' %}

                {% endswitch %}

            {% else %}

                {% include '_partials/_isotope_block_tweet.html' %}

            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

    </div>

    {% if paginate.nextUrl %}

        <div class="ral-load-more-posts nav-previous">

            <div class="container">

                <a class="ral-load-more-posts-text" href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}">Load more posts</a>

            </div>

        </div>

    {% endif %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

Comment: Can you share your pagination template code?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the template code.

Comment: Curious... what's the purpose of the `limit(2)` in the opening paginate block?  It [might not be doing](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4319/57) what you think it's doing.

Comment: I want to set a number of entries per page, in this case 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect if the requested page is greater than the total available pages for the current list of entries like so:

```
{% paginate entries as entriesOnPage %}

    {% if craft.request.getPageNum() > paginate.totalPages %}
        <p>No results</p>
    {% else %}
        {% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
            ...
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

Rather than displaying a message, you could also choose to put an `{% exit 404 %}` tag in there.